# Why does the Select by expression dialog not show field values?

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, mac, osx, gui

I haven't found a similar question that already has an answer so I hope I can get one... Please forgive me if the answer is obvious.
I'm using QGIS version 2.14.0-Essen on my macbook pro with OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. I am trying the simplest `select features using an expression`

Here is the window I get:
[image: As you can see, I don't get unique values window anywhere]
I `right-click` the field (e.g. here `"DIVISION"`) and select say `Load all unique values` but nothing happens. I can check layer values beforehand and enter the correct value and it works (e.g. `"DIVISION"='CENTRAL'`) but it's cumbersome.

**So my question is: How can I get this unique values window to show?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information you are looking for is hidden in a panel that is collapsed/minimized on the right-hand side of the dialog. Here's how you can access it:

[image]

Comment: tnx feel like an iDiot :)